# How to prevent Safari 6.0.2 unexpected crashes in Mountain Lion?

Tags: safari, crash

A few users from a [website I've designed](http://www.archify.com) are complaining about Safari 6.0.2 on their Macs (Mountain Lion, mostly) crashing unexpectedly. In a recent case, a user recorded [this screencast](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgovuyrme6rlsob/Archify%20problem.mp4) using no browser extensions, nor any other tabs: it took only a few seconds for Safari to crash (here's the [crash report](http://pastie.org/private/ypopw9p3z4ypn63gkqfuna)). A quick Google search will reveal loads of similar cases, but none of them seems to provide enough information on the issue, or any potential solution at all. Any idea on what's causing this or how to avoid it? My intention is to prevent Safari 6.0.2 from crashing, as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that, as a *programming* question, it does not belong here.

Comment: Truth is I have no idea if this is a programming question (thus based on my code) or a Apple software (thus based on Safari itself), although I feel this is a bug or rendering issue from Safari. That's why I'm posting this here.

Comment: It's likely a very annoying Apple bug. I am currently having this on both the Macs I use (MacBook Air Core i7, Mac Mini Core 2 Duo). So it's not simply a performance based bug as I thought. Appreciated hearing it happens also with vanilla Safari (I have ClickToPlugin extension on both of these). Apple should be taking this very seriously, but I don't see that happening... Stop supporting your site with Safari 6.x - the only "cure"?

Comment: I just removed the CSS blur filter line and it finally worked. I had to go through almost every single file and line until I found the issue.

Comment: It seems that 6.0.3 may have fixed this issue. The browser still occasionally becomes unresponsive (like it did prior to crashing in 6.0.2) but stays up. Fingers crossed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing CSS3 blur filters seemed to fix the issue. I just went through almost every single file and line until Safari 6.0.2 stopped crashing. Nevertheless, I still have no idea why a single line of CSS3, `-webkit-filter: blur(1px);`, was causing these unexpected crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal app (found in /Applications/Utilties/).
Copy the following as one line (from “curl” through “.pkg”) and paste it into the Terminal window after the “$ ” prompt:

```
curl -O http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/37/23/041-5058/lr5tynbldi18zcrqo8a8uq88 rnjushqliu/Safari6Lion.pkg
```

then hit return.

You should see it count down the time. When it stops, look in your home folder (the one with the little house and your user name) for “Safari6Lion.pkg”. Double-click to launch the installer.

**Here is an alternative solution** that seems to be working for several users, especially those who have somehow managed to install more than one WebKit framework:

1. Open Finder and navigate to:
   /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/ Drag WebKit.framework to
   the trash
2. Run software update and install Safari > do not launch safari after
       it is installed
3. Restart computer
4. Launch Safari

[Let's try!](http://sudungmac.com)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got stuck in the Terminal curl command, though. It seems the file was not found: "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rnjushqliu; nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

Comment: I also tried the alternative solution, but App Store still shows up the "No updates available" message.